# How to set world sky environment for use in libgdx?

Tags: modeling, normals

I'm making a game using libgdx. 
I have to set a sky to my game , using models or another way. 
I looking how to make sky in blender .... I'm so confused. I need help.

For example I've made a sky using a sphere, and applied a skydome image. But in libgdx it is only visible from the outside, when I go into sphere it appears black. I mean the only outside picture seems

Comment: I guess, the is nobody here interested or using libgdx :)

Comment: Well this is **Blender** SE, not libGDX SE ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would need to flip the normals, they are pointing outward, go to *Edit Mode* with your sphere selected. Select all A, from the mesh menu select *Normals / Flip Normals*

[image]

After that you normals should look like (display of normals can be activated by the highlighted button):

[image]

Comment: Actually, i tried it. But i will try again now